# Using the last element from each list in Python

Tags: python

I have this list of lists in Python:

```
[[100,XHS,0],
[100,34B,3],
[100,42F,1],
[101,XHS,2],
[101,34B,5],
[101,42F,2],
[102,XHS,1],
[102,34B,2],
[102,42F,0],
[103,XHS,0],
[103,34B,4],
[103,42F,2]]
```

and I would like to find the most efficient way (I'm dealing with a lot of data) to create a new list of lists using the last element from each list for each id (the first element)..
So for the sample list above, my result would be:

```
[[0,3,1],
[2,5,2],
[1,2,0],
[0,4,2]]
```

How can I implement this in Python? Thanks

Comment: How do you know the size of each sublist should be 3?

Comment: FYI that list isn't valid Python - the item in the middle should be quoted.

Comment: each sublist contains only 3 elements..the ID, a code, and the occurence of that code for each Id...I want to take the count of each code for each id and create n count vectors where n is the number of unique IDs (e.g.100,101 etc)

Comment: The second item of each sublist has to be a string as it contains alphanumeric, otherwise python throws an error.

Comment: @thegrinner It could be valid Python. How do you know XHS isn't a name?

Comment: @kojiro I don't, but either way it's invalid Python as it's posted - either the variable isn't defined or the string isn't quoted. My point is the example isn't the start of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @thegrinner Technically true, but StackOverflow wouldn't be very useful if we required askers to define unimportant terms of data. Letting `XHS` just be a symbol doesn't affect the outcome of this question one way or the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An itertools approach with the building blocks broken out - get last elements, group into threes, convert groups of 3 into a list...

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap, izip

last_element = imap(itemgetter(-1), a)
in_threes = izip(*[iter(last_element)] * 3)
res = map(list, in_threes)
# [[0, 3, 1], [2, 5, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 4, 2]]
```

However, it looks like you want to "group" on the first element (instead of purely blocks of 3 consecutive items), so you can use `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for el in a:
    dd[el[0]].append(el[-1])

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {100: [0, 3, 1], 101: [2, 5, 2], 102: [1, 2, 0], 103: [0, 4, 2]})
```

Comment: I totally missed the groups.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the OP snuck it in as a comment... (well just re-inforced the somewhat subtle way of describing it in the question)

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = []
temp_list = []
counter = 1

for x in list:
  temp_list.extend(x[-1])
  if ((counter % 3) == 0):
    new_list.append(temp_list)
    temp_list = []
  counter += 1
print new_list
```

Comment: This doesn't get his answer.  Look at his required output

Comment: There we go.  That's better.  |=^)

Comment: …This is odd. I downvoted this *before* your edit, but SO won't let me remove the downvote. It *thinks* I downvoted it after your answer. To meta!

Comment: I had to do a [bogus edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71134/158004) in order to remove my downvote.

Comment: @kojiro: edits during the 5 minute grace period do not reset vote locks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do *two* things here:

- Get the last element of each nested list.
- Group those elements by the first element of each nested list.

You can use list comprehension to get the last element of each nested list:

```
last_elems = [sublist[-1] for sublist in outerlist]
```

If the whole list is sorted by the first element (the id) then you can use `itertools.groupby` to do the second part:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[[g[-1] for g in group] for id_, group in groupby(outerlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> outerlist = [
...     [100,'XHS',0],
...     [100,'34B',3],
...     [100,'42F',1],
...     [101,'XHS',2],
...     [101,'34B',5],
...     [101,'42F',2],
...     [102,'XHS',1],
...     [102,'34B',2],
...     [102,'42F',0],
...     [103,'XHS',0],
...     [103,'34B',4],
...     [103,'42F',2]
... ]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [[g[-1] for g in group] for id_, group in groupby(outerlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
[[0, 3, 1], [2, 5, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 4, 2]]
```

If it wasn't sorted, you'd either have to sort it first (using `outerlist.sort(key=itemgetter)`), or, if you don't need a sorted version anywhere else, use a `collections.defaultdict` approach to grouping:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)
for sublist in outerlist:
    grouped[sublist[0]].append(sublist[-1])

output = grouped.values()
```

Comment: I like this answer, but is this the most efficient way to do this?  It is definitely a very concise way to do it.

Comment: @MohammadS.: it is more efficient than using `zip(*outerlist)[0]` in that it doesn't build new tuples for the discarded columns.

Comment: It's amazing how many people *want* to re-answer the [how do you split a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many items are for each key and items for each key go consecutively in the original list, you can use [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby,izip
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [map(itemgetter(-1),it) for key,it in groupby(L,itemgetter(0))]
[[0, 3, 1], [2, 5, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 4, 2]]
```

#### Explanation

Each `it` is an iterator over items with the same key:

```
>>> [list(it) for key,it in groupby(L,itemgetter(0))]
[[[100, 'XHS', 0], [100, '34B', 3], [100, '42F', 1]], [[101, 'XHS', 2], [101, '34B', 5], [101, '42F', 2]], [[102, 'XHS', 1], [102, '34B', 2], [102, '42F', 0]], [[103, 'XHS', 0], [103, '34B', 4], [103, '42F', 2]]]
```

`map` just takes the last element from each sublist:

```
>>> [map(itemgetter(-1),it) for key,it in groupby(L,itemgetter(0))]
[[0, 3, 1], [2, 5, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[100,'XHS',0],
[100,'34B',3],
[100,'42F',1],
[100,'XHS',0],
[100,'34B',30],
[100,'42F',10],
[100,'XHS',0],
[100,'34B',300],
[100,'42F',100]]

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

will print:

```
[[0, 3, 1], [0, 30, 10], [0, 300, 100]]
```